# Moving from mysql to mysqli - problems

Tags: php, mysqli, return

I have the following code:

```
$query3 = "SELECT 
Office, 
COUNT(Office) As Tot_Part, 
(SELECT COUNT(Office) FROM trespondent WHERE completion_status= 'Started' OR completion_status = 'Complete') As Total_Resp 
FROM trespondent 
WHERE completion_status <> 'New' 
GROUP BY Office 
ORDER BY Office";

$result3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
```

I am trying to move from `mysql` to `mysqli` and am struggling terribly.  The above statement brings back only `1` row and not the `26` that there should be.  Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're fetching just one row (`$los = $result3->fetch_row();`).

Try it in a loop.

Like this:

```
$result3 = $mysqli->query($query3); 
while($los = $result3->fetch_row()) { 
    print_r($los); /* sanity */
}
```

Comment: $result3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
while($row3 = $result3->fetch_row()){
 $los = $row3;
} - sadly still no joy.

Comment: @Homer_J Please show updated code... your comment would not work as is either since it overwrites $los 26 times.

Comment: @Homer_J: Please see my edit, for a way to receive feedback of whether it's working or not.